# .htaccess in nginx and php don't work

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx

When I set up an .htaccess file with user and pass for .php file Nginx tries download this file instead of loading it. What can I do to make that functionality work or to replicate that functionality in Nginx

```
location /folder/subfolder/file.php {
    auth_basic "Administrator Login";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
}
```

Comment: You can't use .htaccess files with nginx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.htaccess is for Apache HTTP server but not for Nginx.

There is a [.htaccess to Nginx converter](http://winginx.com/en/htaccess) which can convert your .htaccess settings into a format that will work with Nginx.